# Some windows render slow, others fast?

Tags: compiz, display, macbook, fglrx

2011 8,3 MacBook Pro running 64bit 11.10.

I'm having a pretty weird problem here. After installing `fglrx-updates` and disabling `OpenGL/Sync To VBlank` and disabling `Composite/Detect Refresh Rate`, graphics are running great here with high FPS.

Then, after a while, weird stuff happens. The older windows are, the slower they get when being dragged and rendered.

I'm in the process of uploading a video to demonstrate this, but in the meantime, has this been seen before? Why on earth would certain windows be rendered slower than others?

Answer (score 1):

Unity is to blame.

Unit test: start a program from scratch. Move it with Alt+Left Click or just by the window title bar. Now, try moving it with a triple touch Unity gesture. Good? Now try moving it with Alt+Left Click or by the window title bar.

Unity, you are so much more evil than I took you for. I tried, I really tried to cope with you and accept you for what you are... but you are evil, twisted to the core, there is no hope for you...

Disable the Unity Grab Handles in CCSM and you'll still have multitouch movement, but without the cost of slowing everything down.